# How to concatenate two single column dataframes with different lengths so that DateTime index gets updated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two single column dataframes of different lengths that I would like to concatenate column by column using something similar to:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df_add], axis = 1, join = 'outer')
```

I would like to update df so it has the first column from df and the column from df_add next to it. Not all DateTime indices match (several rows from both dataframes were removed).

My dataframes are:

df:

```
                             col 1
TimeStamp                       
2012-09-20 00:00:00   -11.280400
2012-09-20 00:10:00   -11.945430
2012-09-20 00:20:00   -11.962580
2012-09-20 00:30:00   -12.074700
2012-09-20 00:40:00   -11.923750
                         ...
2019-05-09 23:40:00   690.570129
2019-05-10 00:00:00   565.838928
2019-05-10 02:00:00  1154.415039
2019-05-10 22:00:00   347.493195
2019-05-12 07:20:00          NaN

[345850 rows x 1 columns]
```

and df_add:

```
                             col 2
TimeStamp                       
2012-09-20 00:00:00   -12.037120
2012-09-20 00:10:00   -12.575330
2012-09-20 00:20:00   -12.821350
2012-09-20 00:30:00   -11.959330
2012-09-20 00:40:00   -12.103370
                         ...
2019-05-31 23:20:00  1876.394043
2019-05-31 23:30:00  1783.564941
2019-05-31 23:40:00  1554.718994
2019-05-31 23:50:00  1558.073975
2019-06-01 00:00:00  1597.640991

[343128 rows x 1 columns]
```

I would like to obtain something like this, filling the cells that do not match with index with NaN.

[image: I would like to obtain sth like this:]

Unfortunately, when I try the above line of code, a following error appears:

```
Shape of passed values is (952153, 2), indices imply (355645, 2)
```

I will be really grateful for any help!
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [pd.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) - without being able to try it, I'd say that

```
df_added = df.join(df_add, how='outer')
```

will give you what you're after.

Comment: I tried this one. Unfortunately it messes up the whole dataframe nearly doubling the row number. It doesn't correctly enlarge the TimeStamp index size.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be the case - your TimeStamp indexes look fine in the example you gave. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: So the issue with this problem was that I have not checked whether there were any duplicate rows in this dataset. `df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)` is a nice idea here.